# create a random non-singular matrix reliably

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication, matrix-inverse

How can I create a matrix of pseudo-random values that is guaranteed to be non-singular? I tried the code below, but it failed. I suppose I could just loop until I got one by chance but I would prefer a more elegant "R-like" solution if anyone has an idea.

```
library(matrixcalc)
exampledf<- matrix(ceiling(runif(16,0,50)), ncol=4)
is.singular.matrix(exampledf) #this may or may not return false
```

using a while loop:

```
exampledf<-NULL
library(matrixcalc)
while(is.singular.matrix(exampledf)!=TRUE){
  exampledf<- matrix(ceiling(runif(16,0,50)), ncol=4)
}
```

Comment: You could look into the wishart distribution. rWishart will generate from it.

Comment: Covariance matrices are generally non-singular if there is no correlation of the columns. Why not work with the cross-product of a random data matrix?

Comment: Sounds interesting, will you expand on that and propose it as a solution?

Comment: I did try running your example 1000 times and never got a singular result. 100,000 times and got 2 singular results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fairly unlikely that this will produce a singular matrix:

```
 Mat1 <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=4)
 Mat2 <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=4)

 crossprod(Mat1,Mat2)
        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
[1,]  0.8138  5.112  2.945 -5.003
[2,]  4.9755 -2.420  1.801 -4.188
[3,] -3.8579  8.791 -2.594  3.340
[4,]  7.2057  6.426  2.663 -1.235

 solve( crossprod(Mat1,Mat2) )
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    [,4]
[1,] -0.11273  0.15811  0.05616 0.07241
[2,]  0.03387  0.01187  0.07626 0.02881
[3,]  0.19007 -0.60377 -0.40665 0.17771
[4,] -0.07174 -0.31751 -0.15228 0.14582



inv1000 <- replicate(1000, {
                  Mat1 <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=4)
                  Mat2 <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=4)
                  try(solve( crossprod(Mat1,Mat2)))} )
 str(inv1000)
#num [1:4, 1:4, 1:1000] 0.1163 0.0328 0.3424 -0.227 0.0347 ...
 max(inv1000)
#[1] 451.6

> inv100000 <- replicate(100000, {Mat1 <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=4)
+  Mat2 <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=4)
+ is.singular.matrix( crossprod(Mat1,Mat2))} )
> sum(inv100000)
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one method that guarantees (not *is fairly likely*, but actually *guarantees*) that the matrix is non-singular, is to start from a known non-singular matrix and apply the basic linear operations used for example in Gaussian Elimination: 1. add / subtract a multiple of one row from another row or 2. multiply row by a constant.

Depending on how "random" and how dense you want your matrix to be you can start from the identity matrix and multiply all elements with a random constant. Afterwards, you can apply a randomly selected set of operations from above, that will result in a non singular matrix. You can even apply a predefined set of operations, but using a randomly selected constant at each step.

An alternative could be to start from an upper triangular matrix for which the product of main diagonal entries is not zero. This is because the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the elements on the main diagonal. This effectively boils down to generating N random numbers, placing them on the main diagonal, and setting the rest of the entries (above the main diagonal) to whatever you like. If you want the matrix to be fully dense, add the first row to every other row of the matrix.

Of course this approach (like any other probably would) assumes that the matrix is relatively numerically stable and the singularity will not be affected by precision errors (as you know the precision of data types in all programming languages is limited). You would do well to avoid very small / very large values which can make the method numerically unstable.